# CA Agile Central Publisher Using Jenkins Pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, rally

I have been looking for a way to **update Build information to the UserStories in Rally using Jenkins Pipeline Job type**. 
In Maven/Freestyle Jenkins Job type we have an option **CA Agile Central Publisher** under **Post-Build Actions**. 
[image]

I checked the **Jenkins Pipeline Snippet Generator** and found no option to generate step which integrates Rally to Jenkins. How can we use the same CA Agile Central Publisher using Jenkins Pipeline Job or is there any other way to update Rally User Stories from Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot use 'CA AGile Central Publisher' plugin in Jenkins Pipeline Job. But Rally does provide Build Connectors which can be used for doing the job which CA AGile Central Publisher does. Now you can either use the Build Connector provided by the Rally or can create your own build connector using Rally APIs.

In our case, we are using Cloudbees Jenkins and we created our own build connector using Rally APIs because Rally's defualt build connector doesn't work with cloudbees Jenkins even though it is stated in their documnets that developers were able to use their build connector with cloudbees Jenkins but it is still not officially supported to work with Cloudbees Jenkins.

You can find more details [here](https://help.rallydev.com/ca-agile-central-jenkins-connector)